# running an if statement within a foreach PDO

Tags: php, if-statement

When I added the `if` statement that compares the value of times stored in a table with current time, PHP will throw an error. Could not find solution anywhere. Your help is appreciated. here is the code:

```
<?php
//All database times that are 1 hour before stating will be locked in browser not able to reserve any more
$currtime= date("h:i");

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row ) {
    echo '<tr>';
    if ( $row['time']-$currtime=<-1) {
        echo '<td>'.$row['time']='passed'.'</td>'
    };
    else {
        echo '<td>'. $row['time'] . '</td>';
    }
    //the following part is just so you know what follows in my code within the loop

    if($row[$selected_day]=='available') { 
        echo '<td>'. '<a href="read.php?id='.$row['id'] . '&s_t_id='.$row['schd_tut_id'].'&dat='.$selected_day  .'">available</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<td>'. $row[$selected_day] . '</td>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It would be easier if you showed us the error, but might be this : $currtime=<-1 what is that < ?

Comment: `;` before `else` -> `};   else`. Also you cannot calculate time difference that way.

Answer (score 0):

@ Sougata Bose, Thanks man, that misplaced ; after the ending brace was the cause of the page not loading together with that equal sign. Now everything works just fine. Thanks.
The following code just worked fine for me:

```
<?php
//All database times that are 1 hour before stating will be locked in browser not able to reserve any more
$currtime= date("h:i");

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row ) {
    echo '<tr>';
    if ( $row['time']-$currtime<=-1) {
        echo '<td>'.$row['time']='passed'.'</td>'
    ;}
    else {
        echo '<td>'. $row['time'] . '</td>';
    }
    //the following part is just so you know what follows in my code within the loop

    if($row[$selected_day]=='available') { 
        echo '<td>'. '<a href="read.php?id='.$row['id'] . '&s_t_id='.$row['schd_tut_id'].'&dat='.$selected_day  .'">available</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<td>'. $row[$selected_day] . '</td>';
    }
}
?>
```